# onTouch() and clicking ListView element not working together

Tags: android

I'm trying to do this effect:

when finger is touching view (which is in ListView) view is making bigger (by modifying LayoutParams). When view is released it shrinks and open new Activity.

To accomplish this I wrote this code:

```
public final class MakeImageBiggerOnTouchListener implements View.OnTouchListener {

    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(final View view, MotionEvent event) {

        switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
            case ACTION_DOWN:
                 if(view.getHeight() >= (int) (mStartHeight * sScaleY)) {
                    return true;
                }

                ValueAnimator animator = ValueAnimator.ofInt(view.getHeight(), (int) (mStartHeight * sScaleY));

                final ViewGroup.LayoutParams lp = view.getLayoutParams();
                animator.addUpdateListener(new ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator valueAnimator) {
                        lp.height = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                        view.setLayoutParams(lp);

                        imageLp.height = (Integer) valueAnimator.getAnimatedValue();
                        image.setLayoutParams(imageLp);
                    }
                });
                animator.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator());
                animator.start();

                Log.d("xxx", "ACTION_DOWN");

                return true;
            case ACTION_CANCEL:
                makeSmaller();

                return true;
            case ACTION_UP:
                makeSmaller();

                return false;
            default:
                return false;
        }
    }
}
```

And this in activity that has ListView:

```
    mPlacesListView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, SecondActivity.class);
            MainActivity.this.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

My problem is that activity opening doesn't work. View makes bigger when pressed and smaller when release/moved finger but after releasing new Activity doesn't open.

Comment: What does your Logcat says ?

Comment: With this scenario, is your onItemClick is being called or you can try to find position in your onTouch method and start activity from there

Comment: post openActivity(); code

Comment: @user3141985 just ACTION_DOWN -> ACTION_UP

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin I don't understand you. You mean in ACTION_DOWN put openActivity()?

Comment: @MAGx2 no I mean post the code inside the openActivity method

Comment: when action up, means when the touch is released, try to find position of this view and open activity

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin there is just opening Activity via intent

Comment: @MAGx2 then I cant help you without seeing it

Comment: @MAGx2 what is this? Second.Activity.class why with dot

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin sorry, my bad when coping code (I pressed . after pasting)

Comment: @MAGx2 when was MakeImageBiggerOnTouchListener is used post it

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin in log cat I have only ACTION_DOWN and after this ACTION_UP, Android is not going into opening Activity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**problem:**

```
View.OnTouchListener
```

By the time you add it to the `ListView's View` it will then use it as an `ontouch` listener replacing the `setOnItemClickListener` function to the view. So basically it will instead use the `MakeImageBiggerOnTouchListener` for the item touch event of the view completely ignoring the `setOnItemClickListener`.

**solution:**

you need to switch activity in your switch statement instead and pass the **context** to the `MakeImageBiggerOnTouchListener` so you can use that context to call the `startActivity` and the instance of your main activity.

```
        case ACTION_CANCEL:
            makeSmaller();
            //call activity here
            return true;
        case ACTION_UP:
            makeSmaller();
            //call activity here
```